# String or number to Character with jflex

Tags: java, string, char, character, jflex

I'm using jflex and i have to recognize characters, which can be:

- Normal chars, like 'a'
- Numbers, like '\126'

I've made this regular expression (Integer is a macro already defined):

```
Character = (\'.\')|(\'\\{Integer}\')
```

I don't know if it's ok, but my real problem is that i don't know what code i have to put to turn both type of strings into Characters, because this doesn't work:

```
{Character} { this.yylval = new Character(yytext());
              return Parser.CHARACTER; }
```

Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write valid Java: the only constructor for Character is [`Character(char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#Character(char)) but you are invoking `Character(String)`.

You need to extract what you want from `yytext()`.